# How to react on a value changed in swiftrx before it is actual set? (Like willSet only on Observable)

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a Switch, which is an `Observable` called `switchChanged` I can listen to.

```swift
extension Reactive where ... {
   lazy var toggleSwitch: UISwitch = {...}
   var switchChanged: Observable<Bool> {
      return toggleSwitch.rx
      .controlEvent(.valueChanged)
      .withLatestFrom(toggleSwitch.rx.value)
   }
```

I have the case that I would like to listen to `..rx.switchChanged` or `..rx.toggleSwitch.isOn`, but **before** they actually change their value (as `willSet` does).

The scenario would be :

1. Clicking the switch
2. Listening to clicking
3. Calculating if toggling the switch is possible and showing a spinner
4. a. if yes, toggling the switch and ending spinner

   b. if no, not toggling the switch, showing error popup and ending spinner

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, [.touchUpInside](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event) control event would almost match the case you want to cover, but would maybe look weird if someone would drag the switch to on, then back to off since it would trigger anyway.

It looks to me like there's no issue in actually letting it toggle on, putting a spinner, then if it's not possible, returning it to off state with a message that says you can't do that, a little visual extra doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you are proactive about this. Instead of checking if it is switchable *after* the user tries to switch it, do it before. If the user can't change its state, then set its `userInteractionEnabled` to false.